# Show total of Max in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to show the sum of all rows in the grand total of the matrix. Instead, the total is showing the max of all of rows. How do I get the total to show sum of all rows?

[image]

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/show-grand-totals-top-bottom-of-matrix/m-p/370909

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt this generalized set-up - based on a table named `Table` with fields `Category` and `Value` - to meet your needs:

```
=
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table,
        Table[Category],
        "Max", MAX ( Table[Value] )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( Table[Value] ),
        MAX ( Table[Value] ),
        SUMX (
            T1,
            [Max]
        )
    )
```